# weird flickering when using fade css animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions, transition

I'm making a `div` over another `div`, so when you hover the top `div`, you will see the one under it.
the background colors are the same, but when I check it, it makes this weird color before the animation is complete:
[image: screenshot]

I tried all kind of stuff I found online and here but nothing helped.

does anyone know how to fix it?

thanks in advance.

```css
#morningEtgarWrap{
position:relative;
width:25%;
height:260px;
}

#morningEtgar, #morningEtgarDes{
z-index:90;
text-align:center;
}

#morningEtgarExp, #morningEtgar{
background-color:#7126C6;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align:center;
}

#morningEtgarDes, #morningEtgarName{
height:70px;
background-color:#FCED1D;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}

#morningEtgarImg{
padding:20px;
max-width:60%;
}

.headDesMorningEtgar{
font-size:14pt;
letter-spacing:2px;
}

 #morningEtgarDes{
padding:10px;
}

#morningEtgarWrap:hover #morningEtgar{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
}

#morningEtgarWrap:hover #morningEtgarDes{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="morningEtgarWrap">
<div id="morningEtgar">
<img id="morningEtgarImg" src="http://localhost/et-garim/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Asset-2-1.png"/>
</div>

<div id="morningEtgarDes">
<div><span class="headDesMorningEtgar"><b>עתגר בוקר</b></span>
<br/>
לחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש לפתיעם.<br/> <b>עוד ></b>
</div>
</div>

<div id="morningEtgarExp">
לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית. סת אלמנקום ניסי נון ניבאה. דס איאקוליס וולופטה דיאם. וסטיבולום אט דולור.
</div>

<div id="morningEtgarName">
<div><span class="headDesMorningEtgar"><b>עתגר בוקר</b></span>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that _weird color_ might just be the `div` fading out and therefore it is at roughly 50% `opacity` at that point in time? See [How Opacity Works](https://appendto.com/2016/04/5-examples-to-help-you-understand-how-css-opacity-works/). The things you could do are: 1. Make the animation `ease-out` quicker so the time at that particular `opacity` is shortened. 2. Don't use that effect

Comment: please add that photo to your code so you can effect. it has local address now.